# Brightway 2.5 ecoinvent import stuck in never-ending loop

Tags: brightway

Disclaimer: I know very little to nothing about coding. Maybe the issue below is easy to understand for you, and I actually do hope so.

I am trying to import ecoinvent, with code that worked for me when using Brightway2. However, now that I try to use Brightway2.5, it's not working anymore. This is the code I'm using:

```
import bw2data as bd
import bw2io as bi

bd.projects.set_current("project")

bi.import_ecoinvent_release(version="3.9.1",
                            system_model="consequential",
                            username="abc",
                            password="xyz")
```

This is showing up when I run the code. Obvioulsy, I had to stop it at a certain point.

```
C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\python.exe C:\Users\labc10000\PycharmProjects\pythonPabcr51\ecoinvent.py 
Databases dictionary with 0 objects
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: ensure_categories_are_tuples
Applied 3 strategies in 0.01 seconds
4718 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
100%|██████████| 4718/4718 [00:00<00:00, 12990.14it/s]
Vacuuming database 
Created database: ecoinvent-3.9.1-biosphere
Extracting XML data from 18856 datasets
Databases dictionary with 1 object(s):
    ecoinvent-3.9.1-biosphere
Databases dictionary with 1 object(s):
    ecoinvent-3.9.1-biosphere
Databases dictionary with 1 object(s):
    ecoinvent-3.9.1-biosphere
Databases dictionary with 1 object(s):
    ecoinvent-3.9.1-biosphere
Databases dictionary with 1 object(s):
    ecoinvent-3.9.1-biosphere
Databases dictionary with 1 object(s):
    ecoinvent-3.9.1-biosphere
Databases dictionary with 1 object(s):
    ecoinvent-3.9.1-biosphere
Databases dictionary with 1 object(s):
    ecoinvent-3.9.1-biosphere
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: ensure_categories_are_tuples
Applied 3 strategies in 0.01 seconds
4718 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: ensure_categories_are_tuples
Applied 3 strategies in 0.01 seconds
4718 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: ensure_categories_are_tuples
Applied 3 strategies in 0.01 seconds
4718 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: ensure_categories_are_tuples
Applied 3 strategies in 0.01 seconds
4718 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: ensure_categories_are_tuples
Applied 3 strategies in 0.01 seconds
4718 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: ensure_categories_are_tuples
Applied 3 strategies in 0.01 seconds
4718 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: ensure_categories_are_tuples
Applied 3 strategies in 0.02 seconds
4718 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: ensure_categories_are_tuples
Applied 3 strategies in 0.01 seconds
4718 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\ecospold2.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.data = extractor.extract(dirpath, db_name, use_mp=use_mp)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\extractors\ecospold2.py", line 134, in extract
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 215, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 306, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 329, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 164, in get_preparation_data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\ecospold2.py", line 124, in __init__
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 140, in _check_not_importing_main
    self.data = extractor.extract(dirpath, db_name, use_mp=use_mp)
       raise RuntimeError(''' 
  RuntimeError :   
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

        To fix this issue, refer to the "Safe importing of main module"
        section in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html
         
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\extractors\ecospold2.py", line 134, in extract
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 131, in _main
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^prepare(preparation_data)

  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 246, in prepare
        return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 215, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 297, in _fixup_main_from_path
    self._repopulate_pool()
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
        File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 306, in _repopulate_pool
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 291, in run_path
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 98, in _run_module_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\PycharmProjects\pythonPabcr51\ecoinvent.py", line 13, in <module>
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    bi.import_ecoinvent_release(version="3.9.1",
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\ecoinvent.py", line 239, in import_ecoinvent_release
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 329, in _repopulate_pool_static
    soup = SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\ecospold2.py", line 126, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    raise MultiprocessingError(
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\ecospold2.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^    self.data = extractor.extract(dirpath, db_name, use_mp=use_mp)^
^^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\extractors\ecospold2.py", line 134, in extract
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 215, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 306, in _repopulate_pool

  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 329, in _repopulate_pool_static
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 164, in get_preparation_data
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 140, in _check_not_importing_main
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

        To fix this issue, refer to the "Safe importing of main module"
        section in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html
        

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 164, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 140, in _check_not_importing_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 131, in _main
    raise RuntimeError('''
bw2io.errors.MultiprocessingError: Multiprocessing error; re-run using `use_mp=False`
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 246, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 297, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 291, in run_path
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 98, in _run_module_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\PycharmProjects\pythonPabcr51\ecoinvent.py", line 13, in <module>
    bi.import_ecoinvent_release(version="3.9.1",
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\ecoinvent.py", line 239, in import_ecoinvent_release
    soup = SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\ecospold2.py", line 126, in __init__
    raise MultiprocessingError(
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\ecospold2.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.data = extractor.extract(dirpath, db_name, use_mp=use_mp)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\extractors\ecospold2.py", line 134, in extract
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 215, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 306, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 329, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 164, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 140, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
bw2io.errors.MultiprocessingError: Multiprocessing error; re-run using `use_mp=False`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\ecospold2.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.data = extractor.extract(dirpath, db_name, use_mp=use_mp)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\extractors\ecospold2.py", line 134, in extract
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 215, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 306, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 329, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 164, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\labc10000\Miniconda3\envs\pypyr51\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 140, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

        To fix this issue, refer to the "Safe importing of main module"
        section in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html
```

It actually kept on going even further, but I have left out a part for 'readability'.
Anybody who can help? Thanks!